# Replace "^M" in redirected stdout/stderr *on the fly*

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script that emits "^M" characters and want to replace them with UNIX carriage returns on the fly. Currently, I am redirecting its output and error to a file like so:

```
bash my_script.sh > my.log 2>&1
```

I know that I can use `tr` to perform the replacement, `tr '\r' '\n'`, but I only know how to do this with static text files, and I like to check the output log before the command finishes running. How do I do the replacement on the fly with redirects?

**Edit**: The script needs to have both stdout *and* stderr redirected to the log.

Comment: What do you mean with *true carriage returns*?

Comment: @hek2mgl They mean UNIX carriage returns. UNIX == true :)

Comment: Just a terminology aside: the platform-neutral terms _newline_ / _line break_ / _line ending_ are better terms to use; _carriage return_ specifically refers to ASCII character `0xd` (CR, `\r`), as used as part of the CRLF (`\r\n`) sequence on _Windows_.
If your input has CRLF newline sequences - as opposed to just CR, which is rare these days - then you should simply _delete_ the CR (represented as `^M`) instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bash my_script.sh |& stdbuf -oL tr '\r' '\n' > my.log
```

Comment: That was my first thought, but this does not work, the log file is empty until the command completes.

Comment: This is because of buffering. See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Comment: I'm not sure if it's because of buffering. When I run the command with the `tr` included, I'm actually seeing the output on the standard output again. Usually, nothing is emitted by the script (it goes straight into the log file).

Comment: @Aaron and @slim: I think the issue here is that the output is actually being emitted by the script in the stderr stream, and the | is only piping stdout. That's why there's a 2>&1 at the end of the command. So I need to pipe both stdout *and* stderr through `tr` or `sed`.

Comment: @Guillochon amended - if you want stderr to go into tr too, then you need the redirect before the pipe.

Comment: @slim Perfect, I can never get the pipe ordering right! I was able to avoid the buffering issue by adding `stdbuf -oL -eL` to the `tr` command. So full command is `bash my_script.sh 2>&1 | stdbuf -oL -eL tr '\r' '\n' > my.log`.

Comment: @Guillochon: There is a short-hand for `2>&1 |` in bash, check my answer.

Comment: @Guillochon `stdbuf`'s `-eL` flag isn't needed as the `tr` command will output nothing on `stderr`. You only needed the `2>&1` on the previous process or the `|&` instead of `|` so that `tr` receives the error output of the initial process on its standard input.

Comment: Great, so the final command is `bash my_script.sh |& stdbuf -oL tr '\r' '\n' > my.log`. Thanks guys! Not sure whose answer to accept, all very helpful!

Comment: @Guillochon I've deleted mine since `tr` seems to work well enough, hope it makes the choice easier ;)

Comment: I've accepted your edit, but I was doubtful, because the stdbuf aspect is in there to address a concern that's not described in the question. Suggest you update the question (and title) to bring in the buffering issue.

Answer (score 3):

Here's something that should work for you:

```
bash myscript.sh | sed -u 's/\r/\n/' > my.log 2>&1
```

This will do replacements on the fly while the command is running and still write to the log file.

From the sed man page:

```
-u, --unbuffered
load minimal amounts of data from the input files and flush the output buffers more often
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a short-hand in `bash` for [piping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines) both `stdout` and `stderr` as `|&` .And to just delete the `\r` character with `tr` as

```
bash script.sh |& tr '\r' '\n' > my.log
```

Also, you could disable output buffering if you need, by doing `stdbuf -oL` and then have the `tr` command just after it.

Comment: Similar to @slim's answer, but this also does not work; the log file is empty until the command completes. I need to do the replacement on the fly, with output still being piped to the log file as the script runs.

Comment: I gave `stdbuf` a try, and same outcome: No log output until the command completes.

Comment: The `\&` shortcut is nice!

Comment: So to be clear I want to replace the character (I want there to be UNIX endlines in the output), but your answer is useful for people who might be interested in deleting them entirely.

Comment: @Guillochon: Updated the answer for the replacement, should make sense now!